# Glob pattern arugments into function not recognised and file not found in bash

Tags: bash, shell, glob, hpc

I am trying to write a bash script and pass some globing pattern as arguments into a complex function. However the globing pattern was not recognized by the function and i received a prompt,

```
EXITING because of fatal input ERROR: could not open readFilesIn=ABC001_2_good_????.txt
```

The function i am using,

```
cat acc.txt | xargs -I{} ...--readFilesIn $Dir/{}_1_good_????.txt .....
```

acc.txt contains the list of accession, e.g. ABC001, ABC002, ABC003.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the shell expands wildcards (or tries to) before passing them as arguments to `xargs`. That means it's looking for files with names that literally start with "{}*1_good*", so it fails. Since there were no matches, it gets passed (unexpanded) to `xargs`, which replaces the "{}" with the actual prefix, but by then it's too late for the `????` part to be treated as a wildcard.

It looks to me like the simplest solution is to use a shell loop instead of `xargs`:

```
while read prefix; do
    STAR .... --readFilesIn "$Dir/${prefix}_1_good_"????.fq "$Dir/${prefix}_2_good_"????.fq --outFileNamePrefix .......
done <acc.txt
```

In this form, the shell will substitute `$Dir` and `${prefix}`, and *then* expand the wildcards, so it should work. But be aware that if it finds more than one match it will go ahead and include all of the matched files, which'll probably confuse the `STAR` tool.

BTW if you use `$prefix_1_good_`, it'll treat the `_1_good_` as part of the variable name, so you must use `${prefix}` instead of just `$prefix`. I also added double-quotes around the variable expansions, because that's just good general scripting hygiene.

Comment: Hello thank you for your kind assistance and time to answer the question. I tried using your code but remained to have the same issue. `EXITING because of fatal input ERROR: could not open readFilesIn=$Dir/ABC001_1_good_????.fq`

Comment: Unsure why the function is still not recognising the wildcharacters ????.  in this case, would the ultimate solution be writing a function to remove the last 4 characters after the last underscore, provided the "_good_" matches in the filename?

Comment: The first thing I'd check is that `$Dir` is resolving to the right directory. Does it literally list "$Dir" in the error message? If so, that'd explain the problem. Otherwise, is it an absolute or relative path? If it's relative, what is it relative to?

Comment: it shows the absolute directory in my screen and it works fine it other shell and function but just not this one

Comment: Does it show that absolute path in the error message? Also, in the script, is the command-line option `--readFilesIn` separated from the filename by a space, or an equal sign? One more test: right before the `STAR` command, try `ls "$Dir/${prefix}_1_good_"????.fq` and see if that expands properly; if not, try `ls "$Dir/ABC001_1_good_"????.fq`, and if that doesn't work replace `$Dir` with the actual path and see if *that* works.

Comment: Oh god Gordon you are a genius. I tried the ls comment as you instructed and somehow it expands properly and then i feed into the code you provided; it works totally fine this time; I think it might be the spacing of the argument when i was integrating it. Thank you very much again

Comment: Is there an `=` or a space between `--readFilesIn` and the filename? 'Cause if there's an `=` instead of a space, it'll treat `--readFilesIn=` as part of the path, and that'll prevent it from finding anything.

Comment: When i run the funtion the = is automatically added after `--readFilesIn`. i normally leave a space after that

Comment: That's not a problem, then. As long as the `=` is something that `STAR` adds, not something that bash sees, it shouldn't prefent the wildcard from expanding.